# RewirteRule .htaccess exception

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Maybe this question was already asked million times. But I still haven't find the right answer for my problem.

I want to pass username in url just like what other social networking sites like facebook do. The url should be like : `www.mysite.com/username` and need to be rewrite as `www.mysite.com/?ref=username`

but every time I tried to load another page like `www.mysite.com/register/` it won't take me to that dir but rewrite that url instead.

this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/member-area/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/register/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
#hiding .php extension
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ?ref=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ?ref=$1
```

what is wrong with that? I'm really sorry for asking this question, but I kinda stuck on this situation.

Comment: Use a RewriteCond beforhand or an assertion `(?!register)` in the match regex. -- You do realize *why* the bland /usernname A-Z+ approach conflicts with other rules?

Comment: Just move/duplicate your second RewriteCond for the last two rules.

Comment: how to do that? can you explaining that directly. I'm sorry, I still learning how to create htaccess properly.

Comment: you mean like 
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ?ref=$1` 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/member-area/?$`

Comment: yep, found it. thanks @mairo for marked this question.